# Github list of tag and release asset urls

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I'm struggling with the github graphql interface to get the data that I need. I want to get a list of asset urls for both tags and releases. It seems that some repos produce my desired result while others produce nothing.

```
query {
 repository(owner:"erlang",name:"otp") {
    releases(last:100) {
      edges {
        node {
          url
          releaseAssets(last:100) {
            edges {
              node {
                downloadUrl
              }
            }
          }
          tag {
            name
            target {
              ... on Commit {
                zipballUrl
                tarballUrl
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    tags:refs(refPrefix:"refs/tags/", last:30) {
      edges {
        tag:node {
          name
          target {
            sha:oid
            commitResourcePath
            ... on Commit {
              zipballUrl
              tarballUrl
              author {
                name
                email
                date
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That query, as is, produces my desired results(or at least some them) whereas owner:"spring-projects",name:"spring-framework" produces tags with no tarball. When I look at the spring-framework repo it obviously has assets for releases.

Why are they not showing in this query? When I look at git every release and tag has assets yet, even in my query, the results are hit or miss. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

target is a [git reference](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/ref/), in that case it can point to a [`Tag`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/tag/) or a [`Commit`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/commit/) object. When it points to a `Commit`, your query returns the expected result since `...on Commit` is not empty. To get the `Tag` as well just try out with `...on Tag` and extract the tagger or the commit it points to depending on what you want. Here is an example :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "spring-projects", name: "spring-framework") {
    releases(last: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          url
          releaseAssets(last: 100) {
            edges {
              node {
                downloadUrl
              }
            }
          }
          tag {
            ...refInfo
          }
        }
      }
    }
    tags: refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", last: 30) {
      edges {
        node {
          ...refInfo
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment refInfo on Ref {
  name
  target {
    sha: oid
    commitResourcePath
    __typename
    ... on Tag {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          ...commitInfo
        }
      }
      tagger {
        name
        email
        date
      }
    }
    ... on Commit {
      ...commitInfo
    }
  }
}

fragment commitInfo on Commit {
  zipballUrl
  tarballUrl
  author {
    name
    email
    date
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22spring-projects%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22spring-framework%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20releases(last%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20releaseAssets(last%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20downloadUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tag%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...refInfo%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20tags%3A%20refs(refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Ftags%2F%22%2C%20last%3A%2030)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...refInfo%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20refInfo%20on%20Ref%20%7B%0A%20%20name%0A%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20sha%3A%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20commitResourcePath%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Tag%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...commitInfo%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20tagger%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20date%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...commitInfo%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20commitInfo%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20zipballUrl%0A%20%20tarballUrl%0A%20%20author%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20date%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Note that in the example above, I've used [fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments) to reduce the query size & improve readibility

My guess is that in case the ref is pointing to a `Tag` object that's an [annotated tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_annotated_tags) which can hold a message, a specific tagging date & tagger info. If it points to a `Commit` object, it's a [lightweight tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_lightweight_tags) which is just linking to a commit

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you for taking the time to create this very informative response. Merry Christmas.